# Traverse multiple foreign keys in Django DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on a project to record all scores shot at a bunch of archery events. They are shot by many people at many events and many different archery rounds. (A "round" in archery is a particular type of competition. For the sake of simplicity let's say there are two: indoor and outdoor.)

Here's a basic ER diagram of the relevant part of my database model:

```
┌───────────┐         ┌───────────┐       ┌────────────────┐        ┌───────────┐
│           │        ╱│           │╲      │                │╲       │           │
│  Person   │──────┼──│   Score   │──┼────│   EventRound   │──┼─────│   Event   │
│           │        ╲│           │╱      │                │╱       │           │
└───────────┘         └───────────┘       └────────────────┘        └───────────┘
                                                  ╲│╱                            
                                                   ┼                             
                                                   │                             
                                             ┌───────────┐                       
                                             │           │                       
                                             │   Round   │                       
                                             │           │                       
                                             └───────────┘
```

You can see that there are two ManyToMany relationships at work here resolved with two junction tables (`EventRound` and `Score`). I'm creating these junction tables manually by specifying the "through" table and "through_fields" in models.py.

I've created a PersonDetailView that allows me to access and iterate through all of the scores in the `Score` table for a specific person. (Thanks to Jaberwocky and his solution at [Detailview Object Relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623088/detailview-object-relations))

```
# views.py
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    template_name = 'person_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PersonDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['scores'] = Score.objects.filter(person=self.get_object()).order_by('-event_round__date')
        return context

# person_detail.html
{% block content %}
<h1>Results for {{ person }}</h1>

<table>
<tr><th>Division</th><th>Score</th><th>Date</th><th>Event</th><th>Round</th></tr>
{% for score in scores %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ score.division }}</td>
        <td>{{ score.pretty_score }}</td>
        <td>{{ score.event_round.date|date:"M d, Y" }}</td>
        <td>{{ score.event_round }}</td>
        <td>{{ score.event_round.round }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock content %}
```

The trouble comes when I try the same strategy with the Events and Rounds. **I'd like to show all the scores associated with a particular event or round and include details about the person who shot the score.**

I can't figure out how to reach through the `EventRound` table and get to the scores stored in `Score`. Presumably, I need to further manipulate the `context` in the `get_context_data` method of the `PersonDetailView`.

Any ideas about how to do this?

**Update:** Here's a portion of my models.py that includes the tables referenced in this post.

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone


class Person(models.Model):
    """
    Contains information about competitors who have scores in the database.
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "People"
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('person_detail', kwargs={'slug', self.slug})


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey("Location", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    scoring_method = models.ForeignKey("ScoringMethod", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey("EventType", blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('event_detail', kwargs={'slug', self.slug})

    @property
    def date_range(self):
        if self.start_date is None:
            return "Unknown"
        elif self.start_date == self.end_date:
            return f"{self.start_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')}"
        else:
            return f"{self.start_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')} – {self.end_date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')}"


IN_OR_OUT_CHOICES = [
    ("Indoor", "Indoor"),
    ("Outdoor", "Outdoor"),
]


class Round(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey("Organization", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_retired = models.BooleanField("Retired", default=False)
    in_or_out = models.TextField(
        "Indoor/Outdoor",
        max_length=30,
        choices=IN_OR_OUT_CHOICES,
    )
    events = models.ManyToManyField(
        Event,
        through="EventRound",
        through_fields=('round', 'event'),
        related_name="rounds",
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['organization', 'name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('round_detail', kwargs={'slug', self.slug})


class EventRound(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey("Event",
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name="event_rounds",
                              )
    round = models.ForeignKey(
        "Round",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="event_rounds",
    )
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through="Score",
        through_fields=('event_round', 'person'),
        related_name="event_rounds",
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Event-Rounds"
        ordering = ['-event']

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.event)


DISTANCE_UNIT_CHOICES = [
    ("yd", "Yards"),
    ("m", "Meters"),
]


class Score(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        "Person",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="scores",
    )
    event_round = models.ForeignKey(
        "EventRound",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="scores",
    )
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    x_count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    age_division = models.ForeignKey("AgeDivision", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    equipment_class = models.ForeignKey("EquipmentClass", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.ForeignKey("Gender", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    distance = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    distance_unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=DISTANCE_UNIT_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.person, self.event_round)
```

Comment: Paste your models.py so we can provide a precise and accurate answer.

Comment: @GrandPhuba Thanks. Post updated. I didn't include the entire models.py since it's about 350 lines. There relevant bits should be there.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also clarify, of your intentions. Currently, you show the list of `Score`s for that `Person`. Do you want to show the list of `Event`s/`Round`s for that `Person`, or for ALL `Person`s. I ask this because your question seems to imply the latter, but your code implies the former (since it's inside the `PersonDetailView`)

Comment: I added an answer to your question for now. If you can answer the above, I can update my answer accordingly

Comment: @GrandPhuba, ultimately I want to show all the scores shot by a particular person, all scores shot at a particular event (by all the people who participated), and all the scores associated with a particular round (by all the people at all the events). I assume I'll need three different views to account for those three goals.

Comment: I updated my code. You are correct, you will need three views, though it is possible to simplify and reduce the amount of repeated code; but I explicitly laid out each view for clarity. Let me know if this works or if we need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filtering using fields of a related model

Since you are simply showing scores, it is best to start working from the `Score` model

```
# Get scores by Event for all rounds and dates
Score.objects.filter(event_name__event=event)

# Get scores by Event-Round for all dates
Score.objects.filter(event_name__event=event, event_name__round=round)

# Get scores from one Event-Round in a specific date
Score.objects.filter(event_name__event=event, event_name__round=round, event_name__date=date)
```

### Applying to your use case

#### Scores by Person:

```
# view.py
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Person      
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    template_name = 'person_detail.html' 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        person = self.get_object()
        context['person'] = person
        context['scores'] = Score.objects.filter(person=person)
        return context

# person_detail.html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Results for {{ person }}</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Division</th><th>Score</th><th>Date</th><th>Event</th><th>Round</th></tr>
        {% for score in scores %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ score.division }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.pretty_score }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.event_round.date|date:"M d, Y" }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.event_round.event }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.event_round.round }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

### Scores by Event:

```
# view.py
class EventDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Event       
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    template_name = 'event_detail.html' 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        event = self.get_object()
        context['event'] = event
        context['scores'] = Score.objects.filter(event_round__event=event)
        return context

# event_detail.html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Results for {{ event }}</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Division</th><th>Score</th><th>Date</th><th>Round</th><th>Person</th></tr>
        {% for score in scores %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ score.division }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.pretty_score }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.event_round.date|date:"M d, Y" }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.event_round.round }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.person}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

### Scores by Round:

```
# view.py
class RoundDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Round   
    queryset = Round.objects.all()
    template_name = 'round_detail.html' 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        round = self.get_object()
        context['round'] = round
        context['scores'] = Score.objects.filter(event_round__round=round)
        return context
        
# round_detail.html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Results for {{ round }}</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Division</th><th>Score</th><th>Date</th><th>event</th><th>Person</th></tr>
        {% for score in scores %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ score.division }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.pretty_score }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.event_round.date|date:"M d, Y" }}</td>
                <td>{{ score.event_round.event}}</td>
                <td>{{ score.person}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? Despite that, did it answer your question or are you still running into problems?

Comment: Python 3.7.5. I've been trying to get your "Scores by Person" solution to work, but the template isn't displaying any score data. I'm trying to figure out what's not working, but I haven't got it yet.

Comment: @TimWilson my bad. You must return the `context` variable

Comment: that did it! I can't believe I didn't notice that myself. Thanks so much for your help.